# Chasing Sharepoint errors

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is there a good reference for setting up logging levels in Sharepoint? I am trying to keep my logs to a manageable, usable size but still get useful information from them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use powershell commands to limit the amount of data being logged.
ULS provides Windows PowerShell cmdlets for a number of operations, including:

```
Changing ULS configuration settings

Trace and Event Level throttling

Flushing current log and starting a new one

Querying and filtering Trace Logs

Merging Trace Logs from multiple machines
```

CmdLet Examples

Noun

Description

Purpose

Get-SPDiagnosticConfig

Retrieves Diagnostic Configuration values.

Diagnostic Configuration

Set-SPDiagnosticConfig

Allows setting Diagnostic Configuration values.

Diagnostic Configuration

Get-SPLogLevel

Returns IDiagnosticsLevel2 objects or displays a list of diagnostics levels.

Trace Log and Event Log Throttling

Set-SPLogLevel

Allows the user to set the trace and event level for a set of categories.

Trace Log and Event Log Throttling

Clear-SPLogLevel

Resets the trace and event levels back to their default values.

Trace Log and Event Log Throttling

New-SPLogFile

Ends the current log file and starts a new one.

Log File Control

Get-SPLogEvent

Reads/queries ULS trace logs.

Trace Log Querying and Filtering

Merge-SPLogFile

Combines trace log files from all farm servers into a single file.

Trace Log Merging

Comment: check here also. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff595318.aspx